# Security vulnerabilities when using version 4 UUID as a path parameter

Tags: rest, security, uuid

We are working on REST APIs where one of the path parameter is user uuid in version 4. Can this account for Information exposure through query strings in url vulnerability as described at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Information_exposure_through_query_strings_in_url ?

I read in few blogs that version 4 UUID are safe as far as security vulnerabilities are concerned.

Can someone throw some light on the above understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Version 4 UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) are random. They do not contain any information about the system. As long as randomness is taken from a good source, they are safe.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the semantics. Sending an arbitrary uuid in the url is perfectly ok, why would it not be? It's just a bunch of random numbers.

However, if that uuid happens to be a session id, csrf token, or anything that is sensitive in any way, then that is a problem. Not because of the uuid, any sensitive data in the url is a vulnerability, because urls get cached in the browser, get logged on proxies and the server itself and so on. So you don't want to send anything valuable for an attacker in the url - and a cryptographically random uuid sounds very much like sensitive, otherwise why would you have it?

Comment: If the UUID is sensitive data, then this vulnerability applies. If it's not sensitive data, then it does not. The next obvious question is what is defined as sensitive data, for which I could not find a good reference from an IT security point of view, though this is helpful https://www.alrc.gov.au/publications/6.%20The%20Privacy%20Act%3A%20Some%20Important%20Definitions/sensitive-information